# Reference counted class using inheritance

Tags: c++

```
class Reference {
private:
    ushort ref_count;

public:
    operator delete() {
        ref_count--;
        if(ref_count <= 0) {
            delete this;
        }
    }
};
```

That's the basic idea I want to achieve. How do I make it so the destructor is only called by operator delete, so I don't have to add a "free" (or something) virtual method?

This is how the reference-counted classes are defined:

```
class Texture: public Reference {
public:
    uint id;

public:
    ~Texture() {
        // Problem: this is called when delete is called,
        // not only from the operator delete() override
        glDeleteTextures(1, id);
    }
};
```

This is for a game engine, where I need the resources to be loaded only when they're not loaded already and freed only when all references to them are deleted. I don't want shared_ptr, I want a simpler wrapper.

Comment: Make the destructor private and virtual in Reference.

Comment: You cant make `delete` use reference counting semantics. Once `delete` is called on an object, the object is no longer valid. If you are using C++11 or later, you should use `std::shared_ptr` and let it handle reference counting and deletion for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You can tell that's not what I want

Comment: @jv110 I know what you want. You can't make `delete` work that way. Period. `std::shared_ptr` does what you need. Get rid of `Reference` and use `std::shared_ptr<Texture>`. Now you have a safe reference counted `Texture` object. If you are not using C++11, you can use `boost::shared_ptr` instead. If you don't have boost, then you have to stick with manual reference counting, but overloading `operator delete` is not the right way to implement reference counting

Comment: Fine. I created a virtual method `free` instead.